# Scroll a sortable vertically, not horizontally, without static position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Consider a panel with a long list of items, which you want to drag and drop around. If the list is a jQuery sortable, making it scrollable vertically traps the elements inside.

[this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZhk8/2/) shows the problem. I would simply like to set:

```
.scroll{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:visible;
}
```

Obviously it's never that simple with CSS. Overflow is affected by position in magical ways. The only way i can make it work, is to set the `.scroll` position to `static` (see [how nice](http://jsfiddle.net/PZhk8/3/)).

This is undesirable though, for several reasons which i hope are obvious to many stylers. Anybody knows how to make this work with an `absolute` or `relative` position?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add the `containment:true` option and set it to the container where your sortable lives. This way, it won't go beyond the left and right margins.